# mat accordion is not working on component selectors

Tags: angular, angular-material

how to bind the mat accordion on different components

```
    <div class="dataDiv">
      <mat-accordion>
          <app-waiting-for-approval></app-waiting-for-approval>
          <app-cancel></app-cancel>
          <app-published></app-published>
          <app-system-error></app-system-error>
          <app-test-in-progress></app-test-in-progress>
      </mat-accordion>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="dataDiv">
  <mat-accordion>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      title coming here
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <app-waiting-for-approval></app-waiting-for-approval>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       second title coming here
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <app-cancel></app-cancel>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       second title coming here
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <app-published></app-published>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       second title coming here
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <app-system-error></app-system-error>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       second title coming here
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <app-test-in-progress></app-test-in-progress>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</div>
```

Can you try this?

example link: [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/papbpdybnqm?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: sorry first I thought its md-bootstrap, I edited my answer This should work